# To prove Divergency of a series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\;\;\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty U_n\;$ be a divergent series of positive real numbers.

Then, show that the series $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{U_n}{1+U_n}\;$ is divergent.

Is there is any easy method to prove it?

Comment: What have you tried?  If you haven't tried anything, then take a step back to think independently about the series, jot down your thoughts, attempts, etc., then come back to edit your post to include those notes. If you have tried already, then summarize the process you took in your attempts.

Comment: Any way, provide us with "a method to prove it", and then define what you mean when you ask about "any easy method to prove it",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume, for the sake of contradiction,  that $\sum_n \frac{U_n}{1+U_n}$ is convergent.

Then $\dfrac{U_n}{1+U_n} \to 0$, hence 
$$U_n = \frac{\frac{U_n}{1+U_n}}{1-\frac{U_n}{1+U_n}}\to 0$$
so that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $0\leq U_n \leq 1$ for every $n\geq N$.

Since
$$
\frac{U_n}{1+U_n} \geq \frac{U_n}{2}\qquad \forall n\geq N,
$$
by comparison we conclude that $\sum \dfrac{U_n}{1+U_n}$ diverges, reaching a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $U_n\geq 0$ and that $\sum \frac {U_n}{1+U_n}$ is convergent.

$$\begin{aligned}\sum\left(1-\frac {1}{1+U_n}\right)& convergent\\
&\Rightarrow\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(1-\frac {1}{1+U_n}\right)=0\\
&\Rightarrow\lim_{n\to+\infty} U_n=0\\
\implies \frac {U_n}{1+U_n}\sim \frac {U_n }{1}
\end{aligned}$$
This implies that $\sum U_n$ is convergent, which proves that $\sum \frac {U_n}{1+U_n}$ is divergent by contrapositive.

Comment: Sorry but how does $\lim U_n=0$ follow?

Comment: If lim n→+∞ Un=0 then how we can say that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\∞ Un is convergent? @Salahamam_ Fatima

Comment: Your edit cleared it up - thanks

Comment: @Jam $\sum W_n $ converges $\implies lim W_n=0$

Comment: @SANDIPSHARMA What you say is not what i said.

Comment: You don't reach a contradiction , you've proven the statement's contrapositive, thus proving the statement.

Comment: That is, you start by assuming ONLY the negation of the consequent in the implication you aim to prove.  Then you conclude, with steps in between,  with the negation of the antecedent.  That's a proof by contrapositive, since $p\to q \equiv \lnot q \to \lnot p$

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong, just suggesting that you remove the words "which is a contradiction." (to what? ). Instead point out that, since you have proved the contrapositive of the statement to be proved, you have proven the statement.

Comment: @amWhy I did what you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Nice work, Salahamam!

Comment: I never say that. i say that if a series converges, its general term goes to ZERO.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}U_n=0$ does **NOT** imply that $\sum U_n$ converges.

Comment: No No. take $\sum 1/n $

Comment: But after showing that limn→∞Un=0 you you wrote " This implies that ∑Un is convergent"

Comment: @SANDIPSHARMA they are equivalent $\sim $.

Comment: @zipirovich  You haven't read closely enough: Salahaman starts with an understanding that we speak of $U_n \geq 0.$  $(2)$ Suppose $\sum \frac {U_n}{1+U_n}$ is convergent.  From that, he argues and ends to conclude that $((1), (2)) \implies $ U_n$ is convergent.  That is, it's a perfectly logical direct proof that the contrapositive of the implication posed in the question is true, and hence, the original implication holds.

Comment: Who donwvote correct answer. someone who understand nothing.

Comment: What kind of equivalency is  $\sim$  and how does it help us to conclude that $\sum U_n$ is convergent?

Comment: @miracle173 $a_n\sim b_n $ means $a_n=b_n (1+\epsilon (n)) $ with $\lim \epsilon =0$. if $a_n\geq 0$ then the two series have the same nature.